# Unable to generate CSR for admin approval using below kubernetes YAML file

Tags: kubernetes

I am using below Kubernetes YAML file for generating CSR for user authentication. However, I am getting an error

YAML:

````
apiVersion:  certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: akshay
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  usages:
  - client auth
  request: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURSBSRVFVRVNULS0tLS0KTUlJQ1ZqQ0NBVDRDQVFBd0VURVBN
           QTBHQTFVRUF3d0dZV3R6YUdGNU1JSUJJakFOQmdrcWhraUc5dzBCQVFFRgpBQU9DQVE4QU1JSUJD
           Z0tDQVFFQTdoSWlVNHVyV0thdzliSStyK2MvWFh3clZjSGE2Y0ZFbTBrVElOOCtCcW05Ck5ZdW1T
           OHYrZVFab1NPWEFzdnliTHZWaHphMGZBSllPZzloOGpIZnFzM1ZubXJBa3FPdXJ6ZEdwSXR6aHlP
           S0IKaGZXVXcxZlpqUE85bUZVM3NaYzVHSVpDZE5wb1VWbFozcUFycUxZanZrdXZsUXhyVHY4TDQ0
           MkpNZkp2UXhqTApuNHVndUVKMHNkZ0hrQWZscjNyb3kyeDNiczFOenY1U3VUVnkyQmQzV0o4SVc2
           TXU0SHNXaTV3NFRCemJCUE4vCnBPTDJ3MTlZZ2xzMTU5em5FazhTK0kybTc2Yy9nckkvOFV2b2pv
           VUxlZ0FtZzBBZjRaajBCSUVqOVRzRzVkZXUKY0duRmtnWng4NU1mVnl2U3VOVTdaTFU0a3g0c3N6
           dC9XZlMzcVNiQUR3SURBUUFCb0FBd0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTgpBUUVMQlFBRGdnRUJBRFNWY25lWEM5
           QjRLV200L0RSNkUxKzkrWWhGWUpKcmVSQXplTXpvU1FQQzJldDFNMXc2CjU5NUczZDh2eUNPSk9j
           RFAyREVOM0N0RTBnK0dqZ2R5K29ITy9FL1ZjOXlGZlUrU1dqRll0L0d5OXVNYU1vOTcKWFhIV2V4
           MWZZc0pXR21RajRZOEQyTm1QM1V0eGU3NEVBOTdjaG9ZM0ZWM0xIYWdRZnRRVXFCZ1UrZ2laTlhj
           VwpuTmFuR3JqR25Wd1VYVngxK3hMVjVSR3BQUTNMRnVKR2dpY3VnbWhqYnV0dGtsN3hPS2Q2WTkv
           UVdPa0xNMkxwCjNNSy9idTJSbjQwZ2E0SGV2T3NqUmd2UDV4MzkweStHUXFHMmFrWmw3bVhJMjZO
           d2phdDU3MGtFb2I4c05xS1UKM3lUTldDeERKOWt6dm0vRFAybUo1aE5veVJqN1RSbDhrOWs9Ci0t
           LS0tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFIFJFUVVFU1QtLS0tLQo= ```


ERROR: ```Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "cert.yaml": CertificateSigningRequest in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a CertificateSigningRequest: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequest.Spec: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec.Usages: []v1beta1.KeyUsage: Request: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 76, error found in #10 byte of ...|tLS0tLQo=","usages":|..., bigger context ...|Ci0t LS0tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFIFJFUVVFU1QtLS0tLQo=","usages":["client auth","server auth","digital si|... ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#create-certificate-request-kubernetes-object) a bit of formatting change as below should work.

```
apiVersion:  certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: akshay
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  usages:
  - client auth
  request: 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
```